# itextpdf font does not embed in Linux

Tags: linux, pdf, fonts, itext, embedding

I have a simple Java program that uses iTextPDF to create a simple "Hello World" file, using a font that's not native to iTextPDF (COOPBL.TTF, straight from Windows).

Running on Windows 7-64 it runs fine and creates a pdf file with a subset of the Cooper Black font embedded in the file, reflected in the file appearance.

Running the exact same class file on Linux (no recompile), it does not embed anything and uses Helvetica.

Here's the program:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.itextpdf.text.FontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper;


public class iTextTest {
  private void doit(String sOut) {
    Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);

    try {
      FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(sOut);

      // Register a non-native font.
      String sFontDir = ".";
      int iResult = FontFactory.registerDirectory(sFontDir);
      if(iResult == 0) {
        System.out.println("TestPDF(): Could not register font directory " + sFontDir);
      } else {
        System.out.println("TestPDF(): Registered font directory " + sFontDir);
      }
      System.out.println("  Fonts registered:");
      for(String sFont:FontFactory.getRegisteredFonts()) {
        System.out.println("    " + sFont);
      }

      PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, fOut);

      doc.open();

      XMLWorkerHelper helper = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();

      String htmlContent;
      htmlContent  = "<HTML><HEAD></HEAD><BODY>";
      htmlContent += "<P style=\"font-family: cooperblack;\">";
      htmlContent += "Hello World!";
      htmlContent += "</P>";
      htmlContent += "</BODY></HTML>";
      helper.parseXHtml(pdfWriter, doc, new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlContent.getBytes()));

    } catch(IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(DocumentException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(doc != null) {
      doc.close();
    }
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    if(args.length != 1) {
      System.out.println("Usage: iTextTest outfile");
      return;
    }

    iTextTest test = new iTextTest();
    test.doit(args[0]);
  }
}
```

I'm using:
  itextpdf-5.5.0
  xmlworker-5.5.0
  Windows Java 1.6.0_21
  Linux Java 1.6.0_23

I would include copies of the font and the resulting pdf's, but don't see an apparent way of doing that.  For my tests, I simply copied \Windows\fonts\COOPBL.TTF into the test directories, both for the Windows test and the Linux test.

For what it's worth:
- Tweaking the protection/properties flags in the font file makes no difference.
- I'm aware this isn't a public domain font.  I'm only using it for testing.

I'm all ears for any comments!

Thanks,
Chuck

Comment: You define `String sFontDir = ".";` but `"."` will be different on Windows when compared to Linux. Please write the absolute path of `"."` to the `System.out` and I'm pretty sure it won't be what you expected on Linux. You'll have to move the `COOPBL.TTF` file to the path returned by Linux.

Comment: Thanks, Bruno,

I tried getPath, getAbsolutePath, and getCanonicalPath, and all return the expected results for the current directory from which I'm running the test, on both OS's.

Please note that I list the registered fonts after calling registerDirectory().  According to FontFactory.getRegisteredFonts(), the font file is being registered and I'm using the exact name of one of its incarnations (cooperblack).

Comment: That's strange. I've never seen that problem before. I run all examples on both Windows and Linux. To fix this problem, I'd need to be able to reproduce it, but I can't.

Answer (score 2):

After debugging side-by-side on Windows and Linux (Windows Ecplise and console jdb -ack!), I figured out the problem.  It seems like either a documentation shortcoming, or an oversight on my part.  I thought I'd post the fix here in case someone else has had a similar problem.

The problem is that I should not have been using the default FontFactory to register fonts if I'm going to use the XMLWorkerHelper to parse the file.  The flavor of XMLWorkerHelper.parseXHtml() that I used in the first code sample creates its own FontFactoryImp, XMLWorkerFontProvider.  That provider ignores any registration carried out by the default FontFactory.

The fix is two-fold:
1) Create your own XMLWorkerFontProvider. use the constructor that takes a font directory as an input parameter.
2) Pass that provider in to parseXHtml(), rather than using the shorter call.

I also set the default FontFactory provider using FontFactory.setFontImp().  I haven't studied the subtle implications of that action, but it's easy enough to skip that step or not.

It's worth mentioning that the only reason the original program worked in Windows was that the default XMLWorkerFontProvider that was being provided *inside* my original call to parseXHtml() registers all fonts in all system directories.  Since, on the Windows side, I was using a font that was already in C:/Windows/fonts, that's the one that was being picked up, not the file in the local directory.  If I had used a new font that wasn't registered in Windows, the Windows test would have failed, too.

Here's the working solution.  It produces the same pdf file on Windows and Linux:

NOTE: If you're using XMLParser.parse() instead of XMLWorkerHelper.parseXHtml(), check out the additional comments after this code block.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;

import com.itextpdf.text.FontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerFontProvider;


public class iTextTest {
  private void doit(String sOut) {
    Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);

    try {
      FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(sOut);

      // Register non-native fonts in a directory.
      String sFontDir = ".";
      XMLWorkerFontProvider fontImp = new XMLWorkerFontProvider(sFontDir, null);
      FontFactory.setFontImp(fontImp);

      System.out.println("  Fonts registered before parsing:");
      for(String sFont:FontFactory.getRegisteredFonts()) {
        System.out.println("    " + sFont);
      }

      PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, fOut);

      doc.open();

      XMLWorkerHelper helper = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();

      String htmlContent;
      htmlContent  = "<HTML><HEAD></HEAD><BODY>";
      htmlContent += "<P style=\"font-family: cooperblack;\">";
      htmlContent += "Hello World!";
      htmlContent += "</P>";
      htmlContent += "</BODY></HTML>";
      helper.parseXHtml(pdfWriter,
                        doc,
                        new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlContent.getBytes()),
                        XMLWorkerHelper.class.getResourceAsStream("/default.css"),
                        null,
                        fontImp);

    } catch(IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(DocumentException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(doc != null) {
      doc.close();
    }
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    if(args.length != 1) {
      System.out.println("Usage: iTextTest outfile");
      return;
    }

    iTextTest test = new iTextTest();
    test.doit(args[0]);
  }
}
```

In a late-breaking update, I also had to tweak code that used XMLParser.  The problem was similar.  The default HtmlPipelineContext creates its own XMLWorkerFontProvider.  As with the case outlined above, this will ignore any fonts that you've registered using the default FontFactory.registerDirectory().  Again, the solution is to use your own XMLWorkerFontProvider and then provide it to HtmlPipelineContext.  Then you'll need to create a new CssResolverPipeline for your own XMLWorker, which is then passed to the XMLParser constructor.

Here's a small block of code illustrating this (with a custom image handler):

```
  htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(new CssAppliersImpl(fontImp));
  htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

  pdfImageProvider = new PDFImageProvider();  // Optional
  htmlContext.setImageProvider(pdfImageProvider);  // Optional

  Pipeline<?> pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, new PdfWriterPipeline(doc, pdfWriter)));
  xmlWorker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
  xmlParser = new XMLParser(true, xmlWorker, charsetUTF8);
```

I hope this saves someone the several days it took me to track down!

Comment: In my case(windows\fonts), It was pick from system font folder but when I deployed on linux, ttf not found